# How to retry before an exception with Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using Eclipse + PyDev, although I can break on exception using PyDev->Manage Exception Breakpoints, I am unable to continue the execution after the exception.

What I would like to be able to do is to set the next statement before the exception so I can run a few commands in the console window and continue execution. If I use Eclipse -> Run -> Set Next Statement before the exception, the editor will show the next statement being where I set it but then when resuming the execution, the program will be terminated.

Can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, this is a Python restriction on setting the next line to be executed: it can't set the next statement after an exception is thrown (it can't even go to a different block -- i.e.: if you're inside a try..except, you can't set the next statement to be out of that block).

You could in theory take a look at Python itself as it's open source and see how it handles that and make it more generic to handle your situation, but apart from that, what you want is not doable.